# Change label color in form with error

Tags: forms, validation, colors, label

I'm buzy with a validation plug-in. When someone clicks on the submitbutton and the required fields are not filled, the border-color of the concerning fields changes to red. My problem however is that I also want the color of the text next to it to change. This is my structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <label for="name">Name*</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</div>
.form.a input.error {border:2px solid #eb053b;}
```

How can I now select the label-element to change the text color? It's not possible with CSS, because you can't select a parent-element, but I don't know how to do it with jQuery.

Comment: Can you share the name of validation plugin you are using, or share a fiddle? In case you are using `jquery validator` (a popular one), just using `label.error { color: #EB053B; }` in your css would suffice..

Comment: Thanks for your reaction! I'm using http://jqueryvalidation.org/  I think it is the one you are talking about. However, when I add label.error { color: #EB053B; } to my code, it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem here is that jquery validation plugin (the same as you mentioned) adds another label[for='name'] element after the input box, and this label has a class error associated with it. I thought it would check if the label already exists, but figures out it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger this event on clicking the submit button

```
if(jQuery('.form.a input').css('border')==2px solid #eb053b){
    jQuery(this).siblings('label').css('color','#eb053b');
}
```

Comment: With trigger this event on clicking the submit button you mean like this?: `$(".buttonlink").click(function (){
  if($('input').css('border') == '2px'){
   $(this).siblings('label').css('color','#eb053b');
  }
 });` I hope you mean something else, because this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, the jquery validator adds a label after the input box by default with a class 'error'. Though I haven't found the hack for stopping the validator from doing this yet, here is something that I practice in my forms.
HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name (required)" name="name">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form.a input.error {border:2px solid #eb053b;}
label.error { color: #ebo53b;}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bvXsW/2/)**

This would produce a meaningful error message in a label after the input box **in red color**.
The error messages can be customized using the `rules` option of jquery validator, the placement of label (before or after) is changed by the `errorPlacement` option.

I'll update my answer if and when I find the exact solution to your problem.

Comment: I succesfully deleted the error message. This can be done in the following piece of code of the validator: `messages:{required:"",remote:"",email:"Please enter a valid email address.",` Just delete the text between the quotation marks. My problem doesn't have to do something with the error message, because every label has an unique text.